# How to find out what version of Ubuntu was originally installed?

Tags: upgrade, log

Given a machine that may or may not have been through a number of release upgrades, how can I find out the version of Ubuntu that was originally installed?  Assuming that logging configuration has not been changed from default.

Comment: You mean "release upgrade"? because `dist-upgrade` is not what take from an ubuntu release to the next.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have not done manual modifications, you should see the utilised installation media on the top of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 10.04 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20100427)]/ lucid main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
```

Apport (the Ubuntu bug reporter) uses `/var/log/installer/media-info` to determine the installation media which contains:

```
Kubuntu 10.04 LTS "Lucid Lynx" - Release i386 (20100427)
```

This only works if you kept the `/var/log/installer` folder.

Comment: Both of the suggestions (/etc/apt/sources.list and /var/log/installer/media-info) worked - they indicated on a 11.04 machine that 10.10 was the original installation.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can go to see older `dpkg.log` file available on the system, and take the older package reported on that:

```
less $(ls -rt /var/log/dpkg.log* | 
  head -1) | 
  awk 'NF == 6 && $3 == "install" { print $4, $6; exit }'
```

then go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and see to what release of ubuntu it belongs.

But this is not errors free, because older dpkg logs can be removed, depending on `logrotate` policy.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  It's a little tricky because Ubuntu automatically zips up older log files, but I was able to unzip them and retrieve the original install package: "base-files 5.0.0ubuntu23".  I got tied up finding the right place at packages.ubuntu.com to query this.  But I can see this answer would be a handy option when other alternatives fail.

Comment: The command I gave take care of gzipped files too.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to run `apport-bug` and click an option to get to the second screen ("Send problem report to the developers?").

The `InstallationDate` and `InstallationMedia` attributes will tell you what version installer you ran and when.